# Create and click A element with target blank

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a new `<a>` element with the `download` property and target blank. This link must not be visible in html and will be clicked with JavaScript.

```
let a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
a.href = blobUrl;
a.target = "_blank";
a.download = "MyFileName.pdf";
a.click();
```

Result in HTML:
[image]

The problem is that the target blank seems to be ignored. It worked until recently and there have been no changes. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try: `a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Comment: Why would you need this to open in a blank window, if you set the `download` property? Current browsers should be smart enough to _not_ replace the current document, when they realize the current action does not result in a new document to display, but a download dialog needs to be offered instead.

Comment: @CBroe in my case I set browser to show PDF documents in browser. Whit or whitout target blank I get the same behavior: PDF opens in the same tab. Same behavior in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and also please move the **document.body.appendChild(a);** to the end just like what I have done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>

    function createA(){
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
        a.href = "#";
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.download = "MyFileName.pdf";
        a.click();
        a.innerHTML = "SomeText";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
    
    createA();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: The final result for me]
Please let me know if your problem has been solved by voting the answer :)

Comment: How is this an answer? You've just added some text in the element. But OP's says it's a hidden element, so don't think thats gonna matter.

Comment: Hello @0stone0
can please COPY and PASTE and show me the hidden A and post as an answer? 
First, it is hidden you just see the InnerHTML and you think it is shown, no,  and second if he/she need to remove the InnerHTML just remove that, the answer for this in not the InnerHTML you are seeing, I have told him to move the position of append.

anyways try copy and paste that :)

Comment: @AwatITWork unfortunately same behaviour

Comment: @erikscandola
Can you please edit your question and provide me a screenshot?

Comment: @erikscandola
Thank you, but it seems the link has been added correctly, and now you want to trigger that link to go to the page? I have created a function for that and called it right below, so after the page has been loaded it will trigger that function.